# Release app crashes instantly when run. Debug version is fine react native android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I can run my app fine on my phone while debugging but by running npx react-native run-android --variant=release
or making a release apk through android studio it crashes as soon as I open it. For what's in the logcat  ithink the react-native-background-task might be to blame. Even though I tried to uninstall it. Maybe it wasn't uninstalled correctly.

adb logcat *:E

```
p(Looper.java:193)
08-20 23:46:52.037 21966 22003 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
08-20 23:46:52.037 21966 22003 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
08-20 23:47:04.089 22076 22133 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
08-20 23:47:04.089 22076 22133 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.perkunos.daily_dharma, PID: 22076
08-20 23:47:04.089 22076 22133 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to call create() at least once to create the singleton
08-20 23:47:04.089 22076 22133 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.evernote.android.job.JobManager.instance(JobManager.java:159)
08-20 23:47:04.089 22076 22133 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.jamesisaac.rnbackgroundtask.BackgroundTaskModule.initialize(BackgroundTaskModule.java:52)
08-20 23:47:04.089 22076 22133 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.doInitialize(ModuleHolder.java:236)
08-20 23:47:04.089 22076 22133 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.markInitializable(ModuleHolder.java:100)
08-20 23:47:04.089 22076 22133 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceInitialized(NativeModuleRegistry.java:103)
08-20 23:47:04.089 22076 22133 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$4.run(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:542)
08-20 23:47:04.089 22076 22133 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
08-20 23:47:04.089 22076 22133 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-20 23:47:04.089 22076 22133 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
08-20 23:47:04.089 22076 22133 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
08-20 23:47:04.089 22076 22133 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
08-20 23:47:04.089 22076 22133 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
08-20 23:47:05.064  1211  1365 E storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
08-20 23:47:07.842 22161 22194 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
08-20 23:47:07.842 22161 22194 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.perkunos.daily_dharma, PID: 22161
08-20 23:47:07.842 22161 22194 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to call create() at least once to create the singleton
08-20 23:47:07.842 22161 22194 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.evernote.android.job.JobManager.instance(JobManager.java:159)
```

React Native version:

```
System:
    OS: Linux 4.17 Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz
    Memory: 1.68 GB / 7.70 GB
    Shell: 4.3.48 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.18.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.5 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_201 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.16 - /home/daniel/anaconda2/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: ~16.11.0 => 16.11.0 
    react-native: ~0.62.2 => 0.62.2 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Comment: For what I can see it has to do with the Evernote class, I would advise you to debug and check it out when the function there is being called, and bring some of the code here with these details.

Comment: How can I find this class? I tried doing
 grep -R 'com.evernote.android.job.JobManager.instance' android
But nothing was found. Greps with simpler searches have too many instances

Answer (score 1):

It was the react-native-background-task unnistallation that was causing problems, either I did it wrong or something went bad. [Installing it again](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task) with all the steps did the trick.